# Передача значение отмеченных checbox через ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Пытаюсь с помощью ajax передать значения отмеченных checbox в обработчик "Function.php". Значения вроде бы передаются и потом преобразуются в строку. Для проверки вывожу полученный массив после преобразования в строку, в нём всё правильно, но функция почему-то не отрабатывает.
Когда я перехожу на эту страницу значение уже не выводится. Это значение должно вывести из бд нужные мне записи. Я скорее всего не правильно понимаю принцип работы ajax запросов. Если я отправляю массив чекбоксов через action, то всё срабатывает. Но страниц с checbox у меня 2, поэтому приходится использовать ajax. Помогите понять что я делаю не так?
[image: проверяю отправились ли данные на сервер]
Страница с checbox;

```
      <form id='form'>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="1"/ >Рязанский</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="2"/>Спасский</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="3"/>Касимовский</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="4"/>Клепиковский</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="5"/>Кораблинский</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="6"/>Михайловский</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="7"/>Пронский</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="8"/>Ряжский</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="9"/>Сапожковский</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="10"/>Сараевский</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="11"/>Сасовский</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="12"/>Скопинский</li>
           <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="13"/>Шацкий</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="14"/>Шиловский</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="15"/>Старожиловский</li>
            <li>
                <input  type="checkbox" name='pid[]' value="16"/>Кадомский</li>
            <li>
                <input class="knopka" type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Далее"/>
            </li>


        </ul>


        </form>
```

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#form").submit(function (e) { 
           e.preventDefault();
            var form_data = $(this).serialize(); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "Function.php", 
                data: form_data,
                success: function () {
                 //location.href = 'Spec.php'; 
                }
            });
        });    
</script>
```

обработчик Function.php

```
require_once 'connect.php';
ini_set('display_errors','On'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
global $massiv;
global $aDoor;
global $array;


if (isset($_POST['pid'])) { $aDoor = $_POST['pid'];}


   //выборка регионов
  if(empty($aDoor)) 
  {
        $posts = get_categories();    
  } 
  else
  {
$N = count($aDoor);
      for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
       $array[] .= $aDoor[$i];
        $massiv = implode(",", $array);     
    }
          $posts = get_categoriess();    
  }

echo ($massiv);
 //Все записи
function get_categories() {
    global $link;   
    $sql =  'SELECT * FROM ссузы';
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $categories = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $categories;
}
function get_ssuz () {
    global $link;
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ссузы';
    $result = mysql_query($link,$sql);
    $posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $posts;     
}

//Записи по регионам  
    function get_categoriess() {
    global $link;
    global $massiv;
    $sql =  "SELECT * FROM `ссузы` WHERE id IN ($massiv)" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $categories = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $categories;
}
function get_ssuzz () {  
    global $link;
    global $massiv;
    $sql =  "SELECT * FROM `ссузы` WHERE id IN ($massiv)";
    $result = mysql_query($link,$sql);
    $posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $posts;   
}
```

Comment: Очень сложно понять вопрос. Напиши, пожалуйста, что у тебя есть и что надо получить. Если надо переходить на разные урлы и запоминать предыдущее действие, то ajax тут не поможет.

Comment: @fedornabilkin Суть в том что у меня есть сайт с несколькими страницами с checbox, мне нужно сначала с одной страницы запомнить значения выбранных потом со следующей, передать всё это в файл обработчик, и там уже идёт выборка через запрос из бд, на основе этих значений. Результат выводится на отдельной странице. Когда у меня была одна страница с checbox, данные передавались через стандартный action и всё работало, но с 2 так не проходит

Comment: Надо с первой страницы передать данные на сервер и сохранить их где-то. В сессию, в кэш и т.д. На второй странице проверить наличие данных с первой страницы, получить данные со второй страницы, сохранить и потом уже все эти сохраненные данные на третьей странице получить из хранилища (кэш, сессии), обработать и вернуть ответ.

Comment: @fedornabilkin спасибо, попытаюсь сделать. Можно ли через куки?

Comment: Да хоть через что, главное сохранить данные между запросами. Но куки в браузере, а сессии на сервере. И еще не забыть подчистить данные из хранилища, после обработки.